# Developer left, How do I recover my App?

Tags: facebook

How can I get hold of an App where the only Developer with Admin Access is not reachable? Can I recover and administrate the App using my App Id and Secret Key?

Answer (score 0):

I think that's a problem, because you can only add a role to an existing app via the Graph API if you have a User Access Token of one of the administrators of this app:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/app#roles

An App Access Token (which you could generate with App Id and App Secret) is not enough.